# Show preloader element while waiting for server response using FETCH

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, preloader

I don't get to see my preloader before requested data is displayed using `fetch` I've done some research and my `showLoad` and `hideLoad` show work just fine but still does not show my `loader` element. Any Idea on how to make it work?

```
let searchButton = document.getElementById('button')
let showInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('conteinerInfo')
showInfo[0].setAttribute('id', 'mainddiv')
let divId = document.getElementById('mainddiv')
let loader = document.getElementById('load')

function showLoad(){
     loader.classList.add('display')
    
}

function hideLoad(){
    loader.classList.remove('display')
}

function getWeather () { 
 
showLoad()
fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXX&q=${input.value}&aqi=no`) 
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => { 
    hideLoad()
   let celsius  = 'Temp' + ' ' + res.current.temp_c + " " + '°C'
divId.innerHTML =  celsius

})
} 

searchButton.addEventListener('click', getWeather)
```

```
<div class="conteinerInfo">
    <div id="load"></div>
</div>
```

```
#load{

    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3; 
    border-top: 5px solid #3498db; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin-left: 160px;
    display: none;
  }

  #load.display{
    display: block;
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```css
#load.display {
    display: block;
}
```

to

```css
.display {
    display: block;
}
```